# Validar al menos un checkbox no funciona

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un código de validación de al menos un checkbox en javascript.

Me basé en [este ejemplo](https://ignorante.wordpress.com/2007/09/19/validacion-de-formularios-como-cancelar-la-ejecucion-de-un-evento/)

Ya que permite detener el proceso hasta que la validación sea hecha.

No logro hacer funcionar el código.

```js
function validate(e) {
  var formulario = document.form;
  for (var i = 0; i < form.choice.length; i++) {
    if (form.choice[i].checked === 0) {
      alert ('debes seleccionar al menos una opción');
      if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
      } else {
        e.returnValue = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name = "form" onsubmit = "validate(event, this);">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "chice" value = "valor1" />
<input type = "checkbox" name = "chice" value = "valor2" />
<input type = "checkbox" name = "chice" value = "valor3" />
<input type = "checkbox" name = "chice" value = "valor4" />
<input type = "submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Esta si valida al menos uno -->

```js
 function validate(e) {  
  var formulario = document.form;
  var al_menos_uno = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < formulario.chice.length; i++) {
   if (formulario.chice[i].checked) {
    al_menos_uno = true;
   }
  }

  if (!al_menos_uno){
   alert ('debes seleccionar al menos una opción');
   if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
   } else {
   e.returnValue = false;
   }
  }
 }
```

```html
<form name = "form" onsubmit = "validate(event, this);">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "chice" value = "valor1" />
<input type = "checkbox" name = "chice" value = "valor2" />
<input type = "checkbox" name = "chice" value = "valor3" />
<input type = "checkbox" name = "chice" value = "valor4" />
<input type = "submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Funciona bien, tan solo ponle un `break` en el `if` después del `true`.

Comment: Esto funciona bien.

Answer (score 2):

Estas llamando mal los elementos en javascript actualmente tienes tu metodo validate asi:

```
function validate(e) {
var formulario = document.form;
for (var i = 0; i < form.choice.length; i++) {
if (form.choice[i].checked === 0) {
alert ('debes seleccionar al menos una opción');
if (e.preventDefault) {
e.preventDefault();
} else {
e.returnValue = false;
}
}
}
}
```

Debería ser asi:

```
function validate(e) {
  var formulario = document.form;
  for (var i = 0; i < formulario.chice.length; i++) { //debes usar tu variable formulario, no form ya que no esta definida
    if (formulario.chice[i].checked === false) { //aqui estabas llamando mal el nombre de los checks esta chice, no choice
      alert ('debes seleccionar al menos una opción');
      if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
      } else {
        e.returnValue = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Al final tu script quedaría:

```js
function validate(e) {
  var formulario = document.form;
  for (var i = 0; i < formulario.chice.length; i++) {
    if (formulario.chice[i].checked === false) {
      alert ('debes seleccionar al menos una opción');
      if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
      } else {
        e.returnValue = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Validar</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name = "form" onsubmit = "validate(event, this);">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "chice" value = "valor1" />
<input type = "checkbox" name = "chice" value = "valor2" />
<input type = "checkbox" name = "chice" value = "valor3" />
<input type = "checkbox" name = "chice" value = "valor4" />
<input type = "submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Sin embargo ese código te validará que todos los checks estén seleccionados.

Comment: Siguiendo con el mismo código, como se podría poner más de una condición en la función? https://jsfiddle.net/MLTR6/72u99wqg/

Comment: En el codigo que compartio @sergiorivas, en el if que comprueba si se ha seleccionado por lo menos un check, utiliza el operandor logico and(&&) y comprueba que el valor de tu input username sea diferente de "" o diferente de null, por ejemplo: `if (!al_menos_uno && document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value !== "" ){}`